# What purple spider-like pet is this in Oldschool Runescape?

Tags: oldschool-runescape

I was bankstanding and saw a guy standing there with this awesome looking pet I have never seen before.

[image: front view]

[image: closer view]

I looked around on the wiki and it doesnt look like any of the boss or skilling pets. What pet is this and how can I get one?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is an [Olmlet pet metamorphosised to the Vasa Minirio variant](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Olmlet#Variants). It can be obtained by first getting an Olmlet in Chambers of Xeric, and then obtaining metamorphic dust by completing Chambers of Xeric Challenge Mode within the target time as a 1/400 drop.

Comment: Ahh thanks! Ive never done raids so it now it makes sense why it didnt look familiar.

Comment: Do take note as you answered that olmlet is a 1/53 chance drop rate in chambers, that it can only be obtained when you get a purple (rare) drop which is around 1/16 so the actual drop rate is somewhere among 1/848 although this is not yet officially confirmed. While this is not the case for obtaining the dust from challenge mode, this is a clean 1/400 drop rate.

Comment: @mrdeadsven It's worth noting that the crystal dust only has a chance to drop if you complete within a certain time limit that varies based on your party size. Also raids loot aside from the dust is based on points achieved in the raid, so ~1/53 and ~1/16 are rough estimates based on estimated average points per raid. If you are getting more or less points due to upscaling or deaths these rates will vary significantly.

Comment: @disc_code22 great addition, I almost forgot about this since I did my last 300 raids with the same party and we always end with roughly the same points and time.